# After Update Trigger SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Hey guys i created two tables in oracle sql, first one has 2 columns, and the second has 3 columns(one of them is a foreign key from Pk of first table).
I want to create a trigger that AFTER i update the column of the foreign key in second table, will update the other columns according to the value of the pk.

- Table1(**idF**, name)
- table2(id, **idF**, name)

I want to create a trigger that when i update *idF*(foreign key) in table2  will display the same name as in table1.

Comment: Please tag only with the database you are really using.  I removed the extraneous database tags.

Comment: Why? The purpose of a FK is to tie tables together and not have to repeat information.  As shown I see no reason for table2.

Comment: This is just an example for better understanding

Comment: It may be "just an example for better understanding", but @AdrianKlaver's point is very general. Your data model violates THIRD NORMAL FORM of table design. Column `idF` in `Table2` is not a candidate key (it couldn't be primary key in the table even if you wanted it to be), but it still completely determines column `name`. This will cause lots of problems - for example, the need to create triggers like the one you are considering right now. Do not store the dependent attribute `name` in the second table; store it only in the first table.

Comment: If you need the pre-computed name in `Table2`, for example for faster execution of queries, use a **view** (most likely, a materialized view in this case). That's a much better approach than triggers.

Answer (score 1):

You can create trigger in oracle as follows:

```
Create or replace trigger trg_table2
Before update of idf on table2
For each row
When (old.idf <> new.idf and new.idf is not null)
Begin
Select name into :new.name 
  from table1
 Where idf = :new.idf;
End;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this after update trigger on table1

```
delimiter $$
create trigger MyTrigger after update on table1 
for each row
begin
    update table2 set name = new.name where idF = new.idF;
end$$
```

Comment: actually is when i update that foreign key(idF) in table2 that i need the trigger to update the "name" column on table 2 as well.
For example: in table1 a row(idF=1, name="John") i want when i update the idF in table2 to display me the same name as table1